# How do people set up sites like MangaReader and MangaFox? Aren't they illegal?

Tags: manga-production

How do people set up sites like mangareader.net and mangafox.me? Aren't they illegal?

Comment: Simple: They setup a server, pay for a DNS (Domain Name Server), and start developing the client side code (HTML/Javascript) as well as the server side code. Why, do you want your own illegal manga reader site?

Comment: lel, these sites are illegal but why they are still around today?

Comment: Maybe you should ask at law.stackexchange?

Comment: Who knows? Maybe the Japanese don't know about these sites? Maybe they've given up, because every time one of these are shut down, 10 new ones pop up? Maybe they just don't care? Or maybe they *do* care, but those servers are based in a country that doesn't? You might as well ask why people still steal, murder, traffic drugs or humans, or why the pirate bay is still online. Who knows?

Comment: [You commit three felonies a day](http://kottke.org/13/06/you-commit-three-felonies-a-day). Why aren't you imprisoned?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not lawyers. This question might be better asked on https://law.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Just because it's illegal doesn't mean you can't do it.***

(You'll probably have a lot of legal headaches and risk going to jail etc - but you can still do it - killing people is also illegal, yet people do it)

Just as how the [PirateBay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pirate_Bay) is still around, despite many copyright claimers' objections - these site use loopholes in the law to get around legal restrictions.

- **Ignoring take-down notices**

Usually blatant copyright infringement will have relevant parties emailing [take-down notices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notice_and_take_down), but many of these sites will ignore these. The next step for interested parties is to file a law-suit - which many smaller groups do not have the funds to pay for.

- **Selectively applying takedown notices**

Some sites simply take down the particular series that have been claimed against - and no more. Seeing as English companies are the most interested in preventing English copyright infringement, series that haven't been licensed usually get ignored in take-down lists.

- **Complying with take-down notices, but restarting under a new alias**

There are several sites that close down after legal pressure, but then start right back up again under a new alias - this means legal pursuers have to start the process all over again, for presumably the same result.

- **Hosting tricks**

Sometimes these sites will get around copyright laws by hosting their website in a country that has a copyright policy that makes this website legal. I don't know of many examples but I do know the Pirate Bay tried to buy the [micronation Sealand](https://torrentfreak.com/the-pirate-bay-to-buy-sealand/).

- **Not actually Hosting the content**

Manga readers sometimes don't actually store the content on their servers - they are simply an interface to someone elses' server and consequently, they try to blame that group if anything is contested. Some countries have enforced [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider)-level blockages on some piracy sites to stop infringements in their country.

---

There are some other tricks they use to avoid getting caught, mostly to do with international differences & ambuguity in law.

**I do not recommend you try to set one up yourself.** Firstly for your own wellbeing, secondly because in doing so you are taking away from manga artists, who [already don't make much money as it is.](http://altjapan.typepad.com/my_weblog/2011/05/manga-artist-salaries.html)